# Network tracer mac os

Tags: macos, networking, mac

I search a network tracer for my mac on osX 10.7 but I don't find a good sotfware.
I would like a graphic interface (netstat is too root for me :) ) where I can see any request on any port and to any host destination in realtime (if possible).

Do you know a software like this on osX ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me that you're describing Wireshark. 
It can be found at [wireshark.org](http://www.wireshark.org) and requires that you have [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) installed.